# Are $[0,1)\times [0,1)$ and $[0,1]\times [0,1)$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Are $[0,1)\times [0,1)$ and $[0,1]\times [0,1)$ homeomorphic?

Not getting any idea how to start.